# Reset CSS3 timing function with JS

Tags: javascript, css

When the slide gets to the second "1", I need it to seamlessly reset to slide "2" and give the impression of infinite carousel,

The demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/benhowdle89/cWTbn/

The code:

```
$('.wrapper li:first').clone().appendTo($('.wrapper ul'));
var element = $('.wrapper')[0];
element.setAttribute('data-left', 0);
setInterval(function() {
    var mL = +element.getAttribute('data-left'), t = +$('.wrapper').css('width').replace('px', ''), w = +$('.wrapper li:first').outerWidth();
    if(t == (Math.abs(mL) + w)){
        element.style.webkitTransitionTimingFunction = "none";
        element.style.webkitTransform = "none";
        element.setAttribute('data-left', 0);
    }
    element.style.webkitTransitionDuration = "0.3s";
    element.style.webkitTransitionTimingFunction = "ease-out";
    var currentL = +element.getAttribute('data-left');
    var newL = +(currentL + w);
    element.style.webkitTransform = "translate3d(-" + (newL) + "px, 0, 0)";
    element.setAttribute('data-left', newL);
}, 2000);
```

The problem:

After slide "1", it animates back to slide "2", so I need it not to, but to snap back to slide "2" (not visual to the user),

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Move the animation to a separate class. Since you're already using jQuery, you can use the following:

```
$('.animiationClass').removeClass('animationClass').addClass('animationClass');
```

Comment: @DarylGinn He's already using `$('.wrapper li:first')`, which is jQuery.

Comment: @Mooseman I think what Daryl is trying to say, is that I don't think the solution requires jQuery, but is a CSS transition property/value problem